# Connection to websocket server : OK from javascript, not OK from php

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using socketio to run a websocket server.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.be/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.be/fullchain.pem')
};
var app = require('https').createServer(options)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)

app.listen(6666);
```

Connecting to it from javascript (using socket.io client) works fine.

```
var socket = io.connect('wss://my.domain.be:6666');
```

This works also :

```
var socket = io.connect('https://my.domain.be:6666');
```

Now I want to connect using php.
I found a simple php client here : [How can I send data/text from PHP using WebSocket to process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595585/how-can-i-send-data-text-from-php-using-websocket-to-process)

But I see no incoming connection when using :

```
$WebSocketClient = new WebsocketClient('wss://my.domain.be', 6666);
$WebSocketClient->sendData("MyUserNameFromPHP");
```

And I get the error :

> Error: 22145040:Unable to find the socket transport "wss" - did you
>   forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

When using :

```
$WebSocketClient = new WebsocketClient('https://my.domain.be', 6666);
```

I get the error :

> Error: 10905616:Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you
>   forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

When using tls:// or ssl:// I get no output at all (and still no connection on my websocket server).

So what am I missing to make a websocket connection from my php code ?

Comment: Have you tried `$WebSocketClient = new WebsocketClient('https://my.domain.be', 6666);` ? It would seem that "wss" is a socket transport protocol that must be manually added to php (not 100% on this, just what I gather from that error message).

Comment: Then I get : Unable to find the socket transport "https" (added to my original post)

Comment: Try using the ip address of the websocket server instead of the domain name (no protocol or anything in front of it) For example: `$WebSocketClient = new WebsocketClient('111.111.111.111', 6666);`

Comment: Connection on ip address will be refused because the ssl certificate is only valid for the domain "my.domain.be". Although that is what my web-browser tells me when I try this in javascript code (socket.io). Testing this in php gives again no output at all (and no connection on my websocket server).

Comment: Could this be of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28393526/1025702 Maybe you need to enable wss in apache or whatever server you're using?

Comment: Hello Matt. If I understand correctly I need httpd24 & php56 to be able to use websockets from within php. Upgrading from httpd v2.2 to v2.4 is not such a small intervention. But if this is the only way...

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61808878/3701985
 please try my answer on another similar thread, I actually tried multiple solutions and now just want to provide answer which worked for me. 
https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl